# SQL - UPDATE/INSERT FROM Source to Target table

Tags: sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a source table called `STG` which needs to be "merged" with a target table called `MAP`.

```
STG
ID1    HASH    TIME
A     123     12:01AM
A     456     12:05AM
A     789     12:10AM
B     123     12:15AM
B     789     12:20AM
C     987     12:25AM

MAP
ID1   ID2     HASH    TIME
A     A       123     11:55PM
```

`ID1` in `MAP` can have the same column values as in `STG`
The value for `ID2` is determined by the first time `MAP` sees the `ID1` and `HASH` combination.  For example, if row 4, `B     123     12:15AM`, were to be inserted as a single row into `MAP` it woudd look like `B    A    123    12:15AM` due to the fact that the `HASH` value `123` was already in `MAP`, so the existing value of `A` `ID2` is used.

Goal:  "Merge" all the rows in `STG` into `MAP` with the appropriate `ID2` value.

Cases:

1. `ID1` Exists in `MAP`, `HASH` Exists in `MAP`:  `UPDATE(MAP.TIME = STG.TIME)`
2. `ID1` DNE in `MAP`, `HASH` DNE in `MAP`:  `INSERT(STG.ID1, STG.ID1, STG.HASH, STG.TIME)`
3. `ID1` Exists in `MAP`, `HASH` DNE in `MAP`:  `INSERT(STG.ID1, MAP.ID2, STG.HASH, STG.TIME)`
4. `ID1` DNE in `MAP`, `HASH` Exists in `MAP`:  `INSERT(STG.ID1, MAP.ID2, STG.HASH, STG.TIME)`

The problem with tackling the problem in this manner is that some of the rows in `STG` have dependencies on one another.  For instance, I the SQL code to execute Case 2 is ran, the 5th row will be inserted as neither `ID1` and `HASH` exist in `MAP`, but the 4th row has an association with `MAP` via `HASH` value `123`.

Cases 1 and 2, are straight forward and obvious.  Solving for the Cases 3 and 4 while considering the dependencies has proved difficult.

How should Cases 3 and 4 be solved?

The (correct) end result should look like this...

```
MAP
ID1    ID2    HASH    TIME
A      A      123     12:01AM
A      A      456     12:05AM
A      A      789     12:10AM
B      A      123     12:15AM
B      A      789     12:20AM
C      C      987     12:25AM
```

Comment: why row 5 will be in case 2 since there is `A A 789 time...`

Comment: according to the cases, 5th row should  be `B  B  789  12:20AM`

Comment: The 5th row should be as show in the last table.

Comment: If your 5th row is correct then your 2nd case is not correct. Because at least ID1 and ID2 should be equal each other.

Comment: @sarslan - Perhaps I'm looking at it incorrectly.  I'm assuming the 4th row in `STG` should be merged before the 5th row in `STG`.  If this is the case, then the 5th row in `MAP` is correct and was merged by Case 3 or 4.  Should I not make that assumption?  This gets back to the mention of dependencies on the data in `STG`.  If lower rows (larger row #) can't be dependent on higher rows (smaller row #) then I assume I'll have to write some code to do a "clean up?

Comment: @sarlan - above...assuming the 3rd and 4th row in `STG`...

Comment: @user2715877 If you make this update operation row by row then it can be possible. But to make it with a bulk update you have to check values also in STG tables. for example, 3th case could be `ID1 Exists in MAP or STG, HASH DNE in MAP or STG ( except own)`

Comment: @sarslan I guess the easiest thing to do would just have a "clean up" query (UPDATE) to fix this situation instead of having all the individual INSERTS.  Based on my understanding of what you have helped with it would not be possible to account for those situations all within one MERGE query.  Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this.

```
DECLARE @STG TABLE (ID1 VARCHAR(5),   [HASH]  INT,  [TIME] TIME)
INSERT INTO @STG VALUES
('A',123,'12:01AM'),
('A',456,'12:05AM'),
('A',789,'12:10AM'),
('B',123,'12:15AM'),
('B',789,'12:20AM'),
('C',987,'12:25AM')

DECLARE @MAP TABLE (ID1 VARCHAR(5), ID2 VARCHAR(5),   [HASH]  INT,  [TIME] TIME)
INSERT INTO @MAP 
VALUES
('A','A',123,'11:55PM')


;MERGE @MAP AS tar
USING (
        SELECT S.ID1, COALESCE(M.ID1, S.ID1) ID2 , S.HASH, S.TIME 
        FROM @STG S
            LEFT JOIN @MAP M ON (S.HASH = M.HASH OR S.ID1 = M.ID1)
        ) AS src (ID1, ID2, [HASH], [TIME])
ON (tar.ID1 = src.ID1 AND tar.[HASH] = src.[HASH])
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET [TIME] = src.[TIME]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (ID1, ID2, [HASH], [TIME])
    VALUES (src.ID1, src.ID2, src.[HASH], src.[TIME]) ;
```

Result:

```
ID1   ID2   HASH        TIME
----- ----- ----------- ----------------
A     A     123         00:01:00.0000000
A     A     456         00:05:00.0000000
A     A     789         00:10:00.0000000
B     A     123         00:15:00.0000000
B     B     789         00:20:00.0000000
C     C     987         00:25:00.0000000
```

Comment: The 5th row should be `B A 789 time`?

Comment: But according to the cases, 5th row should  be `B  B  789  12:20AM`

Comment: @that's what I am confused with OP's question xD

Comment: The 5th row should be `B A 789 12:20AM`

Comment: I replaced ISNULL with COALESCE and removed `AND tar.ID2 = src.ID2` in the `MERGE` `ON` clause.  Everything works great except for the 5th row issue.

Comment: If your 5th row is correct then your 2nd case is not correct. Because at least ID1 and ID2 should be equal each other.